# Best way to send firebase message or notification that trigger pull request from server

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

- Currently the Android application I have taken in charge performs a "pull" on the server every minute to recover data and update a fragment with this data. Obviously this does not work when the device switches to doze mode. So I decided to use FCM as Google recommends.

**Constraints** :

- The user needs to know that new data is available even in doze mode.
- To not change the application too much, I do not want to send the data in the firebase message but rather send an https request to the server when I receive the fcm message.
- The fcm message must:

  1. Advise the user that new data is available with a notification.
  2. If the user presses the notification ***OR*** returns to the application after turning the screen on, the https request must be triggered and fragment has to be updated.
     I will add that it must be triggered at the latest when the user returns to the application.

**My solution for now**

I used a data message with a high priority instead of a notification message because a notification message need the user to tape the notification to trigger action.

In onMessageReceived :

- I send the notification that redirects to my application.
- I send my request to the server and update my application.

Disadvantage of my solution :

- If my app is killed by the system while the screen was off what's going on?
- My request has a time limit to complete when the phone come out of doze mode.

**Questions :**

- Is this solution the best possible ?
- Is there another way to proceed?
- Perhaps could i schedule a task that runs **immediately** when user resume my app in onMessage received ? But i dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself to close the subject and hope it can help someone !

- After a night ... I definitely do not like the workmanager solution. Even if in practice it can work I do not like to use APIs for unplanned uses. If google tells me that it is not garanty to launch task immediately, they are (much :)) better than me and I believe them!

In this case, I think that my task may be postponed, for example because the OS wants to group calls with other apps. There may be internal conditions i dont know about.

- Especially since I found a much simpler solution.

In onMessageReceived, I use a simple boolean indicator.
In the onResume of the activity I want to update I read this indicator and I launch my request if true for example.

I no longer need a scheduler, and after all if it is not done 100% reliable, it does not matter :

- If fcm could send me a message there is a lot of chance there is a network when the user turn on the screen.
- Even if there is none it is not very serious since I can warn the user who can proceed otherwise (by phoning for example !!!!)

Answer (score 0):

Use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) to schedule the background work to run immediately.  It will also retry until your code indicates that it's successful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have a doubt as indicated in your link : [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) :

"WorkManager is intended for tasks that are deferrable—that is, not required to run immediately—and required to run reliably even if the app exits or the device restarts."

You are right because this task has to be run reliably but is has to be run at the latest when my application resume.

Comment: You can use them to defer for immediate execution.  I've done this before and it works fine.  The only downside is that you don't get a guarantee of immediate execution, but in practice, all the constraints of the job will be satisfied immediately.

Comment: Ok if it is your experience it make sense. I will give it a try.

Comment: https://github.com/CodingDoug/firebase-jetpack/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/hyperaware/android/firebasejetpack/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt